# IIS application pool stopping

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

I'm working on a web app on my local machine and have an application pool created with the identity set to my own credentials. Username and Password are correct.

Every time try to access the website, I get:

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

And the application pool stops.

Everything I've found online is related to a password expiration but that isn't the case here.

**Edit:** When the application pool stops, if I right click on it and select 'Recycle' I get this:
[image]

Comment: it sounds like password expiration indeed... I guess you tried logging off and back on?

Comment: I have, still no good

Comment: create another another app pool and associated with the web app?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use "Local System" or "Application Pool Identity" ? Also, do you have shared configuration enabled ?

Comment: Yeah local system will work, but I need to use my own credentials for the identity. I'm accessing a SQL database in the background, with windows authentication

Comment: It could be a permission issue. Please check if default permissions for IIS are present for it to function correctly. Navigate to Run--->secpol.msc--->Local Policies -->User Rights Assignment. Now, go to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat . Scroll down and compare the permissions present under "Default Windows user rights assignments" section with those listed on your machine. If "Application pool identity" is mentioned as one of the permissions, add the service account that your application pool is using.

Comment: You can also check Event Viewer first to see what error you get there. That should also clarify a lot of things.

Comment: Event viewer: "Application pool DefaultAppPool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool."

Comment: Its definitely a permission issue. Highly recommend to go check Default IIS permissions as listed in my above comment. But even if that does not fix the issue, you can capture a procmon trace and identify what's going on